# Compute area between $y=x$, $x=2$ and x axis, but using Polar coordinates.(without double integral).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Problem: compute area between $y=x$, $x=2$ and $x$ axis, but using Polar coordinates.(without double integral).
My idea is to first calculate "normal" type of integral.
$$\int_0^2x dx=2$$
Secondly I know that boundaries of new integral are $\pi/4$ (because of $y=x$) and 0 (because of $x$ axis).
Also I know that if I want to switch to polar coordinates than $x=r\cos(\alpha)$. But I don't know how to end this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polar equation of the vertical leg $\rho(\theta)=\frac{2}{\cos(\theta)}$ and use the formula:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\rho^2(\theta) \ d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\frac{4}{\cos^2(\theta)}(\theta) \ d\theta=
2\left[\tan(\theta)\right]_0^{\pi/4}=2.$$
Quite a complicated way to compute the area of a right triangle!

P.S. See this [webpage](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx) for more details about hoew to calculate areas with polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain why 2/cos(x)?

Comment: @Lovro Sindičić The vertical leg is along the line $x=2$ then use $x=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and find $\rho$.

Comment: Can you please explain in other way I don't understand.

Comment: @Lovro Sindičić Look at the first picture here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx
You have $\alpha=0$ (because of the $x$-axis), $\beta=\pi/4$ (because of the $y=x$) and $\rho=f(\theta)=2/cos(\theta)$ (because of $x=2$, that is $\rho\cos(\theta)=2$  or $\rho=2/\cos(\theta)$.